# jQuery star rating in a table

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller

I have an MVC application generating a series of radio buttons based on a dynamic set of questions.  The questions are generated, and the star rating works perfectly, but for some reason, when I try to have each radio button in its own cell in a table, once the javascript kicks in, all the radiobuttons appear in just one cell.  Without the javascript, they appear in the correct cells.

I'm using a table because I have a header graphic which explains (I know, it's self explanatory, but that is what was requested) what the ratings mean, which should line up above the questions' star ratings.

Does anyone know of any way to stop the radiobuttons doing this?  I'll probably just end up using CSS, but it would be interesting to know why this happens.

Comment: It'd help if we could see the table markup and javascript in question. If the .js is too big to paste here, can you toss it in a pastebin?

Comment: Would be interested also to know what you mean by "when the JavaScript kicks in". Are you implying that by the mere incusion of the js, your layout changes, or are you saying that upon execution, your layout changes? 
Again, echoing Meredith L. Patterson, code snippets would be useful

Comment: It's the standard jQuery star rating from http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/.  

Yes, when the javascript detects the 'star' class in the inputs, they all move to the cell the first radiobutton is in.  

Example:

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td><input name="star[0]" type="radio" class="star" value="1"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 2</td>
    <td><input name="star[0]" type="radio" class="star" value="2"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>

etc...

Comment: I hardly hope that this post is active..but i am also stuck with the same problem. Can anyone help me? As how to modify the rating.css so as to preserve the  original table struture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to edit the plugin as this will hide the radios and replace them with the stars which I assume is just rendering the elements next to each other ignoring your original td structure.

Comment: had an awful feeling that was the answer - I'll stick to CSS and try to do the layout that way.

Comment: I hardly hope that this post is active..but i am also stuck with the same problem. Can anyone help me? As how to modify the rating.css so as to preserve the  original table struture?